# Function not calling added with document.getElementById('someId').appendChild()

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am getting fraction part of HTML code from api, want to render into DOM like below...

```js
// getting template from backend.
let template1 = "<div class='well'><formio src='example/text.json'></formio>"; //appearing into dom, but not loading form.

// second way
let template2 = "<formio [src]='getUrl()'></formio></div>";
// calling getUrl from component.ts file.

// attaching template into DOM using appendChild() method..
const fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(template);
document.getElementById('landingTemplate').appendChild(fragment);

getUrl() {
   return 'example/text.json';
}
// getUrl() not calling from HTML.
```

```html
<div id="landingTemplate"></div>
```

so unable to render formio. Anyone have idea please help me.

Comment: There is no real reason to use `document.createRange().createContextualFragment(template);`, just simply do what LGSon mentioned below.

Comment: Hmm, posted an answer, still, am I right when saying, it does add the markup but your `formio` component doesn't work?

Comment: If so, I added a few links that might be helpful, and one might even be a possible duplicate...

Comment: document.createRange().createContextualFragment() and innerHtml both are giving the same results. but problem is formio not rendering by this way, while formio is working fine when directly putted into html.

Answer (score 2):

When you have HTML markup in a string, use `innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById('landingTemplate').innerHTML = template;
```

---

Updated

If it does add the markup but your `formio` component doesn't work? ... then here are couple links that might be what you are looking for:

- [Dynamically add Component in angular 2/4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079989/dynamically-add-component-in-angular-2-4)
- [AngularJS: Dynamically add component from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557552/angularjs-dynamically-add-component-from-list)
- [How to dynamically add innerHTML with angular 2 components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473910/how-to-dynamically-add-innerhtml-with-angular-2-components)
- https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: But, `template` is constructed in backticks (es6).. Would this work if you use `.innerHTML` ?

Comment: @DavidR Yes it will. Backticks are for template literals, though it is still a string

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @LGSon !